# SQL Server Query performance with window function

Tags: sql-server, sorting, window-functions

We write a query that include unpivot, partition by and order by.
Query is:

```
SELECT PersonId
    ,SalaryDate
    ,ID
    ,Type
    ,SalaryValue
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY SalaryValue
        ) AS rn
FROM (
    SELECT lp.PersonId
        ,lp.SalaryDate
        ,lp.Salary1
        ,lp.Salary2
        ,lp.Salary3
        ,lp.ID
    FROM rdd.Salaries AS lp WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE lp.SalaryDate > DATEADD(day, - 31, getdate())
    ) AS t
unpivot(SalaryValue FOR Type IN (
            lp.Salary1
            ,lp.Salary2
            ,lp.Salary3
            )) AS UnpivotTable
```

[image]

The query returns about 68.000.000 rows and execution time is 20 minutes. 

Can I improve the query's performance or rewrite effectively? 
What is the alternative of partition by?

Comment: What indexes do you currently have on the Salaries table?

Comment: The index has SalaryDate and include PersonId, Salary1, Salary2, Salary3

Comment: @Armstrong63 is it a composite index, or all indexes alone? Your writing would suggest the first option. Could you please provide entire table schema?

Comment: Table schema is:<br/> `CREATE TABLE [rdd].Salaries (
 ID [bigint] NOT NULL
 ,Salary1 [decimal](18, 3) NULL
 ,Salary2 [decimal](18, 3) NULL
 ,Salary3 [decimal](18, 3) NULL
 ,[SalaryDate] [datetime] NULL
 ,[SalaryDateInt] [bigint] NULL
 ,[SalaryDateIntAll] [bigint] NULL
 ,[ErrorStatus] [int] NOT NULL
 ,[ErrorDetail] [varchar](500) NULL
 ,[PersonId] [bigint] NULL
 ,[RecordStatus] [char](1) NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Salaries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC)
 )
`

Comment: This index is composite index. 
Index is:<br/>`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_rdd_Salaries ON rdd.Salaries (SalaryDate ASC,ErrorStatus ASC,RecordStatus ASC)INCLUDE (PersonId,Salary1,Salary2,Salary3)`

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of the ROW_NUMBER() construct? Do you actually need a ranking of each salary or are you doing something more specific with it, i.e. the maximum, minimum or some type of statistical function of each person's salary?

Comment: Your Sort operator has a warning on it - what is that warning?  eg Spill to tempdb?  Make sure your stats are up-to-date and consider breaking up the query.  Concentrate on removing this warning.  It maybe you put it back together afterwards.  Please post the whole Actual Execution plan XML, eg as a link to Pastebin/ Dropbox / Skydrive etc

Comment: @wBob This warning is : _operator used tempdb to spill data_.

Comment: @Armstrong63, the ORDER BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER() function is causing the sort operator, which is at the heart of your performance issue. Do you *need* the actual row number for each salary row, or is the row number used in another calculation later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that the following index and query rewrite performs better, because it sorts per person rather than once over the whole set, and row estimates are more likely to be accurate:

```
-- Index
CREATE INDEX IX_Salaries_PersonId_SalaryDate_Inc_ID_Salary1_Salary2_Salary3
ON rdd.Salaries (PersonId, SalaryDate)
INCLUDE (ID, Salary1, Salary2, Salary3);

-- Query
WITH People AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        S.PersonId
    FROM rdd.Salaries AS S
    WHERE 
        S.SalaryDate > DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE())
)
SELECT 
    P.PersonId, 
    CA.SalaryDate, 
    CA.ID, 
    CA.SalaryValue, 
    CA.rn
FROM People AS P
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        S.SalaryDate, 
        S.ID, 
        V.SalaryValue, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.SalaryValue)
    FROM rdd.Salaries AS S
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT S.Salary1 WHERE S.Salary1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT S.Salary2 WHERE S.Salary2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT S.Salary3 WHERE S.Salary3 IS NOT NULL
    ) AS V (SalaryValue)
    WHERE 
        S.PersonId = P.PersonId
        AND S.SalaryDate > DATEADD(DAY, -31, GETDATE())
) AS CA
ORDER BY
    P.PersonId,
    CA.rn
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);
```

You can omit the `OPTION` clause if you find a parallel query is generated naturally, or if you find non-parallel performance is good enough. The desired plan shape is roughly as follows:

[image: Plan Shape]